# Reading BLOB data from Oracle database using python

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, blob

This is not a question of a code, I need to extract some BLOB data from an Oracle database using python script. My question is what are the steps in dealing with BLOB data and how to read as images, videos and text? Since I have no access to the database itself, is it possible to know the type of BLOBs stored if it is pictures, videos or texts? Do I need encoding or decoding in order to tranfer these BLOBs into .jpg, .avi or .txt files ? These are very basic questions but I am new to programming so need some help to find a starting point :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pure `BLOB` in the database, as opposed to, say, an `ORDImage` that happens to be stored in a `BLOB` under the covers, the `BLOB` itself has no idea what sort of binary data it contains. Normally, when the table was designed, a column would be added that would store the data type and/or the file name.